# Can't connect to mongo docker image with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a simple docker setup with node and mongo:

**Dockerfile:**

```
 FROM node:8.9.4-alpine
 RUN mkdir /app
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY package.json /app/
 COPY package-lock.json /app/
 RUN npm install
 ADD . /app/
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm run start"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Now in my **app.js** I'm connecting to mongo like that:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

**However I'm getting a** `failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]`

The mongo container seems to boot up and run fine giving me `waiting for connections on port 27017`.

What's wrong with my setup? I also tried swapping out `localhost` for `mongo` when connecting, but it had no effect either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't realise I named my database container db instead of mongo, so all I had to do was to switch that name out in my app.js:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://db:27017')
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think without mounting volumes in `db` service , container won't be able to continue its process. it will start for just a second and then it will be terminated.
so that's why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to look at the port part of your container in the inspector, and my opinion is that you have to put : `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/`

enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:
In docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:7
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: mongo-server
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

Remember at the container_name, name it whatever you want, and then, in the mongoose connection:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo-server:27017/your_table_name")
```

Change "*mongo-server*" that match container_name. Hope it helps.